# Disable JW player 6 on all mobile phones and devices

Tags: php, javascript, android, jquery, flash

From my knowledge, flv can be played on Andriod phones. I want to customize the jwplayer 6 to play the video on web browsers only and disable the player on all mobile phones for publisher embedding option.

- If i use flv format, the video still can be played on Android phones.

  ```
  file: 'http://www.example.com/media/trailer.flv',
  ```
- If i set Primary to "flash" and Fallback to "false" to disable fallback to html5 player, Android phones still can be played the video in flash player.

  ```
  primary: 'flash',    
  fallback: 'false',
  ```
- PHP mobile detection is not secure enough, publisher can send a fake user-agent to fool the script.

Any solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try using Modernizr instead - http://modernizr.com/

That way you're detecting if the browser is capable of the feature and not trying to keep up with the ever-changing and spoof-able world of browser headers.